# Toggle one of many blocks with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I have a few links, which should toggle their corresponding div like this...

```
    $('#link a').click(function() {
        $('#open').animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });

    $('#link2 a').click(function() {
        $('#open2').animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });

    $('#link3 a').click(function() {
        $('#open3').animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });
```

Problem is if you click #link, then click #link2, BOTH boxes stay open.

All the '#open' divs share the same class, so I have used

```
$('#link1 a').click(function() {
        $('shared-class').hide();
        $('#open1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });
```

Which does work, tho it looks very crude as hide does not slide in, If I used a toggle on the class, it mixes up the order of what comes out, and what syas in, I am not sure if there is just a way to slide an element in IF IT IS OUT, hope this makes sense, much apreciated for any help!

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/PEfHc/

Basicly if I click 1, all others should not show

Comment: Hiya, Look for Jquery API `.toggle()` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ That will help, have a nice one bruv, cheerios!

Comment: A JS Fiddle will be help you get fast responses.

Comment: Could you post the HTML of this page.

Comment: @Tats_innit i think http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ or http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ would be more apt here. Blud :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hows you? yeah bruv I realised that after reading the full question but you have `i200 Intel pentium Multicore` Hands and keyboard :)) I concur, you are right, have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: Writing a jsfiddle as we speak :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UBVtU/ might come handy! :) let me know if this suits you I wil set it as answer with explanation. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There surely are easier ways to do this sort of thing, but anyway:

```
$('a', '[id^="link"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $('#open'+$(e.target).parent().attr('id').replace('link', ''));
    $('[id^="open"]').not(elm).filter(':visible').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
    elm.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpepn/)

Comment: Hi Adeneo,

I think this does exactly what I require, only one thing if its possible, is there a way to make the desired box to open once the current one has closed? Rather then them animating at the same time?

Comment: And in the real code, the ID's arnt so nice like 'open1, open2' as I used as an example, will this effect the code? (ID's are generated by wordpress)

Comment: With a little bit of hacking, managed to get this working, many thanks kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
$('#link1 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.shared-class:visible').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#open1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4kTj/2/)

Anyway, this one needs to be factorized, it's just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Hi Shikiryu,

Managed to get the previous one working, tho this is slighlty more readable for a jquery newbie like myself, many thanks :)